# os compatibility on mobiles

Tags: android, windows-ce, webos

i want to develop an application on android,webos,wince. how to develop application that should run on all paltform with developing each paltform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are also a variety of frameworks that allow you to compile them into native apps for multiple platforms.  They typically wont nail every platform, but they will provide a way to make native apps for multiple platforms at once.

Examples are:
[Titanium Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/)
[Rhomobile](http://rhomobile.com/)
[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You best bet would be to develop a web application that users could access through the browsers on their devices.  You wouldn't have access to some - possibly a lot - of the features on each phone, but you would be able to provide a similar look and feel between each device.

Comment: Agree. For different devices not supporting J2MEE, a web application seems the best solution. You just have to play with CSS to be sure that the application feets well on their screens

Comment: Dave is right, the Web is the ultimate cross-OS-compatible development platform.

Comment: Hi dave through web application shall we interact device hardware